# ParentA Child Expands Parent, ParentB Child does not. Exact Same Setup

Tags: html, css

Terrible title, I know.. it's just different than any other "Child expanding outside of parent" problem I've ever had or saw.

Anyway, I have two children with the same structure and same CSS applied to both.

### HTML:

```
<div id='base'>
    <div id='banner'>
        <a href="#" class="current">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#" class="next">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#" class="next">Link 3 with longer width</a>
        <a href="#" class="next">Link 4</a>
        <a href="#" class="next">Link 5 dif size</a>
        <a href="#" class="next">Link 6</a>
    </div>

    <form id='form'>
        <div>
            <div class='col-6-'>
                <p>dd</p>
                <!--<p>dsadosih doijasd oouhvodus ouhfoiusdif oiudhaoudd 
oinoiuasd onhasoiduf ou oud oijod</p>-->
            </div>
            <div class='col-6-'>
                <p>dsadosih doijasd oouhvodus ouhfoiusdif oiudhaoudd 
oinoiuasd onhasoiduf ou oud oijod</p>
                <br>
                <p>dsadosih doijasd oouhvodus ouhfoiusdif oiudhaoudd 
oinoiuasd onhasoiduf ou oud oijod</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
* 
{
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body 
{
    height: 100%;
    color: #0068ac;
}

body {
    text-align: center;
    background: #689976;
}

.col-6-{width: 48%;}


body
{
    background: gray;
}
#base
{
    display: inline-block;  
    padding-top: 5%;
    height: 90%;
    /* width: 90%; */
}
#form
{
    height: 98%;
    background: #E6F0F7;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}
#banner a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 36px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 10px 0 60px;
    color: #ffe143;
    background: #32a252;
    height: 2em;
}
.col-6-
{
    display: inline-block;
}
#form div div
{
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 1%;
}
#form div p
{
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

I've never tried to share a jsfiddle, but hopefully this works: https://jsfiddle.net/12rLb42a/

#### Bottom Line

As you can see there are two divs at 48% width of the parent. The second div contains two p's that wrap within the 48% space and don't breach it.

If you uncomment the p element in the first div, you will see that is not the case for that one because it does expand the parent. Why is this happening?

Comment: Might be because the container `#base` has no defined width. If you give it a fixed with then the paragraph width has something to relate to.

Comment: @ovokuro, that doesn't explain why the second div paragraphs work as intended though..